# How to find variance covariance matrix using mle estimates for a given data in wolfram?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, mathematica-online

```
x = {0.1, 0.2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 11, 12, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
  21, 32, 36, 40, 45, 46, 47, 50, 55, 60, 63, 63, 67, 67, 67, 67, 72, 
  75, 79, 82, 82, 83, 84, 84, 84, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 86, 86}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
n = Length[x]
logL = \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
     1\), \(n\)]\(Log[\[Alpha]*\[Gamma]*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x[\([\)\(i\)\(]\)]\), \(\[Gamma] - 1\)]*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(\[Alpha]*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x[\([\)\(i\)\(]\)]\), \(\[Gamma]\)]\)] + \
\[Lambda]*\[Beta]*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x[\([\)\(i\)\(]\)]\), \(\[Lambda] - 1\)]*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(\(-\[Beta]\)*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x[\([\)\(i\)\(]\)]\), \(\[Lambda]\)]\)]]\)\) + \
\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]\((\(-
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(\[Alpha]*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x[\([\)\(i\)\(]\)]\), \(\[Gamma]\)]\)]\) + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(\(-\[Beta]\)*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x[\([\)\(i\)\(]\)]\), \(\[Lambda]\)]\)])\)\)
sol = Maximize[{logL, \[Alpha] > 0 && \[Beta] > 0 && \[Gamma] >= 
     0 && \[Lambda] >= 0}, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Lambda]}]
mle = {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Lambda]} /. sol[[4]]
```

I am facing issue in getting mle estimates. Is there any issue with the code.can some one help me to sort this out.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two of the maximum likelihood estimates are on the boundary which does not bode well for obtaining a reasonable covariance matrix.  I think you might need better starting values or use a bootstrap to estimate the covariance matrix.

If you had estimates not on the boundaries, then the following would give you an estimate of the covariance matrix:

```
cov = -Inverse[(D[logL, {{α, β, γ, λ}, 2}]) /. sol[[2]]]
```